# How does lm sensors get the cpu wattage?

Tags: hardware, cpu, system-monitor, sensors, lspci

I've been wanting to read my "raw" hardware status, so far I've found that, in my system, I can access said status through `/sys/class/hwmon`. Then, I've been comparing the numbers I've found against the output I get from `sensors`.

For example: if I do `vim /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input` vim shows me a file with only the number `35000` written on it, I then run `sensors` and in the output I can find a line that says `CPU Temperature:    +35.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)`.

Using this method I've managed to pin down where all the data from `sensors` comes from... except for `power1: x W  (crit = y W)`. The context on this line is the following:

```
fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       XX.XX W  (crit = 125.02 W)
```

I've found where the `fam15h_power` data is and I've opened `power1_crit` and it had `125015625` written on it (it seems to be the critical wattage in microwatts). but whenever I open `power1_input`, the number I get has nothing to do with the the output XX.XX W `sensors` gives me. For example: I ran `sensors` and got `power1:  52.74 W  (crit = 125.02 W)`, but the file `power1_input` said `87615291`.  The only relation I've found between these numbers is that they both go up or down together.

So, why does the data from `sensors` seem so unrelated to that of `hwmon/`? (only on the wattage consumption). How does `sensors` calculate or get the wattage? (is that wattage from the CPU?)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, do these help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/746483/how-to-read-lm-sensors-on-amd-fx-6300 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-lm-sensors?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

[Ohm's Law](http://www.electrical101.com/ohms-law.html)

|  | Ohm's Law |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E = I * R | E = Voltage (Volts V) | E = P / I |
| I = E / R | I = Current (Amps A) | I = P / E |
| R = E / I | R = Resistance (Ohms Ω) |  |
|  | P = Power (Watts W) | P = E * I |

[lm-sensors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) can monitor the CPU voltage, and the current used, so it can derive the power (in watts) by calculating watts = voltage * current.